# Simulating of Fraunhofer Diffraction of Zigzags by 2D FFT

Tags: matlab, fft, continuous-fourier

I tried to study the diffraction pattern of the following zigzag grating by Matlab(FFT of this image)..

[image]

And the result showed like this(please ignore the scale bar in this img)

[image]

I think the program of FFT by Matlab is correct.. I am just wondering why, in the FFT, the midpoint(0,0) did not show the strongest intensity..Because I did some calculation by a simple model of zigzag(two lines), the midpoint always shows the strongest brightness..

Any suggestions are welcomed.

Comment: Did you use `fftshift` before visualizing the spectrum?

Comment: YES. fft2(), fftshift(), Then get the real part and imag part. And get the spectrum...Actually I think explanation from physic, fraunhofer diffraction is much more strongly welcomed than from image processing...

Comment: I'm an Electrical Engineer who specializes in image processing, not a physicist... so if you "strongly welcome" an explanation using physics than image processing, then we have nothing more further to say.  This is also a forum about programming, not physics.  If you want a physics explanation, try the Physics StackExchange instead.  http://physics.stackexchange.com/ . Good luck!